# After filling PDF with iTextSharp, form is not savable/ usage rights removed

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, itext

I am currently working on a process that will use iTextSharp to partially fill a PDF form. This form is then emailed to a user and the user will finish completing the form. Then the form is submitted by email back to our email account and then processed.

My problem is that once the PDF is sent out to a user, when the user opens the form and the data can not be saved. The original PDF that is used as a template can be filled out an saved. Somehow, during the process of using iTextSharp, the form is losing its usage rights. Is there a way to retain the usage rights while using iTextSharp?

I am hoping that someone here can point out what is going wrong, or point me in the right direction. Thanks for your time and help.

Below is the code:

```
using Dapper;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using NLog;
using PilotDispatch.Domain.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace eTicketPdfFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        const string TemplateItextPdfPath = @"C:\PDF\Factory\eTicketFormPortrait.pdf";
        const string OutputItextPdfPath = @"C:\PDF\Factory\eTicketFormPortraitOut.pdf";


    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logid = string.Empty;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                logid = args[0];
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Error("No LogId supplied");
                return;
            }

            var rundownQuery =
                string.Format(
                    "SELECT * FROM Rundown_Table LEFT JOIN Vessels ON Vessels.CallSign = Rundown_Table.Call_Sign WHERE Rundown_Table.Log_ID = '{0}'",
                    logid);


            ETicketPdf ticket;
            IEnumerable<PilotTransportation> pilotTransportations = null;

            using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PervasiveConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
               // ticket = cn.Query<ETicketPdf>(PervasiveQueryString, new { Log_ID = logid }).FirstOrDefault(); // not working with Pervasive
                ticket = cn.Query<ETicketPdf>(rundownQuery).FirstOrDefault();

                if (ticket != null)
                {
                    var transportationQuery =
                        string.Format(
                            "SELECT * FROM PilotTransportation WHERE PilotCode = '{0}'",
                            ticket.Pilot_Code);

                    pilotTransportations = cn.Query<PilotTransportation>(transportationQuery);
                }

                cn.Close();
            }

            if (ticket == null)
            {
                Logger.Error("No records found for given LogId");
                return;
            }

           var pilotOptions = pilotTransportations.Select(opt => string.Format("{0} - {1}", opt.VendorID, opt.Name)).ToArray();


            var reader = new PdfReader(TemplateItextPdfPath);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputItextPdfPath, FileMode.Open));
            //var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputItextPdfPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write), '\0', true);
            var formFields = stamper.AcroFields;

            formFields.SetListOption("Form[0].Page1[0].VendorIdFrom1[0]", null, pilotOptions);
            formFields.SetListOption("Form[0].Page1[0].VendorIdTo1[0]", null, pilotOptions);
            formFields.SetListOption("Form[0].Page1[0].VendorIdFrom2[0]", null, pilotOptions);
            formFields.SetListOption("Form[0].Page1[0].VendorIdTo2[0]", null, pilotOptions);

            var properties = ticket.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                var name = prop.Name;
                var propval = prop.GetValue(ticket, null);

                if (propval != null)
                {
                    if (name == "Order_Date")
                    {
                        if(Convert.ToDateTime(propval).Year < 1902)continue;
                    }

                    formFields.SetField(name, propval.ToString());
                }

            }

            reader.RemoveUsageRights();
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();

            File.Copy(OutputItextPdfPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(OutputItextPdfPath) + "/" + logid + ".pdf");

            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, thanks in advance for any pointers or help that you can offer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is commented out in your own source code.

You need:

```
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(...), '\0', true);
```

instead of:

```
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(...));
```

Your question is a duplicate of [How to correctly fill in XFA form data using iTextSharp to allow editing and saving result in Acrobat XI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945972/how-to-correctly-fill-in-xfa-form-data-using-itextsharp-to-allow-editing-and-sav)
and you can find a more elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951821/1622493).

Also: you complain that the usage rights are removed, but if that is so, why do I see this line in your code:

```
reader.RemoveUsageRights();
```

That line removes the usage rights and therfore the form can no longer be saved locally when using Adobe Reader.

Comment: One is the link to the question, the other is the link to the answer. There's nothing to fix but your code. If I can give you some more advice: please read the documentation in the future. If you use a method that is named `RemoveUsageRights()` asking why the usage rights are removed is awkward.

Comment: Sorry that I left the usage rights call in the code. That was for testing purposes. Also, I have swapped the line of code that you stated above. However the result are still not workable. If i email myself the orginal PDF I can fill it out and submit it and get the data out of the submitted pdf. But if i use the newly created PDF, I get an warning from PDF Expert that states "Form data cannot be saved becasue of the file structure. Please resave the file in the latest version of Adobe Live Cycle Designer." So with your changes something is being changed using iTextSharp. @Bruno

Comment: Also... after submitting the data from the generated PDF I am able to see the data that the user filled out in the PDF preview of Outlook 2013, but not able to see the data the was prepopulated. It is just the opposite if i open the PDF in reader or acrobat. I am able to see the data that was prepoppulated, but not the data that the user submitted. So that data is indeed on the form at some levels, but not the dame levels. @Bruno Lowagie

Comment: Are you using an old version of iText? It sounds like a problem that was solved a while ago.

Comment: You were correct. I was using an iTextSharp versioin 4.5... Replaced that with 5.5... But now the four dropdown lists aren't being populated as they were before. formFields.SetListOption("Form[0].Page1[0].VendorIdFrom1[0]", null, pilotOptions) is no longer functioning. Possible update issue?

Comment: Your form was originally an XFA form (one can tell from the naming convention for the fields). Could you share that PDF so that we can test?