# Convert XML to PDF

Tags: java, xml, pdf, itext

I have an XFA based PDF, which is basically a template PDF. I am asked to fill some fields of that editable PDF programmatically. So far, I convert template.pdf to its corresponding XML using itextpdf. Now I wish to edit that XML file and convert it back to PDF. I learned that we can use apache FOP but I only have 1 corresponding XML file and not .xsl file as asked by FOP. Please point me in the right direction.

I used Pdfstamper to fill in some fields, but PDF file doesn't remain editable after I convert it back to PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code I use to convert PDF to XML.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class ConversionClass {

    public static void main(String[] a){
        pdfToXfa();
    }
    @Test
    public static void pdfToXfa() {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("template.pdf");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("template_xml.xml");
            XfaForm xfa = new XfaForm(reader);
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = xfa.getDomDocument();
            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tf.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult((os)));
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using iText already check the [manual](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-5-legacy/xml-worker-examples)

Comment: There is no reference of PdfStamper there, I believe i am breaking signature when converting xml back to pdf. I even took reference from here, but no help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945972/how-to-correctly-fill-in-xfa-form-data-using-itextsharp-to-allow-editing-and-sav